# What are the points we should consider to make the Mobile UI compatible with single thumb usages?

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, mobile-application, users

What are the points we should consider to make the Mobile UI compatible with single thumb usages? other than the most suggested point by everyone and Apple Guideline that that tap size should be 44px.

Some people use left and some right hand.

Comment: Whoever has voted to close the question Please also make a comment here so all can know the problem with the question

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a comprehensive article here that covers most of what you need: http://scotthurff.com/posts/how-to-design-for-thumbs-in-the-era-of-huge-screens

It's based around the iPhone series but most of the information is transferable.

Basically it says don't make users over stretch or over flex: for right-handed users, the bottom right-hand corner is consistently difficult to use - obviously this is flipped for Left-handed users. Other than that, just make sure everything is within a reasonable reach and important stuff is easier to get to that not so important stuff.

There are also some templates to download that you can overlay on your wireframes/UI designs.

Comment: the optimal spots will be in the reach of both thumbs :-)